# Are monad laws enforced in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads

From the Haskell wiki:

> Monads can be viewed as a standard programming interface to various
>   data or control structures, which is captured by the Monad class. All
>   common monads are members of it:
>
> ```
> class Monad m where
>   (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
>   (>>) :: m a -> m b -> m b
>   return :: a -> m a
>   fail :: String -> m a
> ```
>
> In addition to implementing the class functions, all instances of
>   Monad should obey the following equations, or Monad Laws:
>
> ```
> return a >>= k  =  k a
> m >>= return  =  m
> m >>= (\x -> k x >>= h)  =  (m >>= k) >>= h
> ```

**Question:** Are the three monad laws at the bottom actually enforced in any way by the language? Or are they extra axioms that **you** must enforce in order for your language construct of a "Monad" to match the mathematical concept of a "Monad"?

Comment: They are not enforced by the language or compiler. The programmer is responsible for making sure the laws hold.

Comment: Since Haskell is a *Turing complete* language, you cannot enforce any laws on its functions.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That's really misleading.  A turning complete language can still have a proof system and provide guarantees about operations.  For example, many extensions (often SMT based) on top of Haskell can prove the monad laws - do these new extended language suddenly become non-Turing-complete?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I guess it is impossible *in general* to automatically  determine if the monad laws are satisfied in a Turing Complete Language: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: Rices theorem says that every non-trivial language-invariant property of a language *L* cannot be decided. Now evidently there are prove systems that can prove in *some* circumstances that an invariant holds. The point is that this cannot be done for a *generic* instance. Furthermore some extensions can shape the structure in such a way that the sublanguage itself is not Turing complete anymore (for instance a regular language) in which case many properties can be proven.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem But that is not the case here, the language remains turing complete in the cases I've seen.   Moreover, we are not interested in proving a property in general, we are interested in proving the monad laws hold over a few concrete instances which are usually quite simple.  The theoretical issue of full generality has no hold on the practicality of proving properties in the cases of interest.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: I would compare it with the *halting problem* which is well studied. There exists a lot of heuristics that can prove, for most programs whether they will halt for a given input. But you cannot construct a prover that will prove it for any instance. The same holds for monads: you cannot construct a prover that can prove whether monadic laws will hold. But you can get lucky that for a given defintion a heuristic can prove it. That's the consequence of Rice's theorem I think.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, we are both saying much the same thing. Rather verbosely too!

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: But then I don't see what's misleading about the comment. If you implement a simple state monad, it is very likely the prove system will prove the laws hold. If you however implement a weird wacko monad, things are less likely to be proven. So in general - which is as far as I know the question - it cannot be proven.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It is misleading because "Since Haskell is a Turing complete language, you cannot enforce any laws on its functions" suggests to the reader that properties can not be proven about Haskell functions.  Just because a there exist terms and properties you can not prove does not mean all terms are not provable.  In practice it is even more stark, there might exist unverifiable laws but rare is the day you'll run into one in practice.  Just look at many of the liquid Haskell applications - plenty of things are proven about Haskell code.  Same is true for much of Adam Gundry's work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**You** are responsible for enforcing that a `Monad` instance obeys the monad laws. Here's a simple example that **doesn't**.

Even though its type is compatible with the `Monad` methods, counting the number of times the bind operator has been used isn't a Monad because it violates the law `m >>= return = m`

```
{-# Language DeriveFunctor #-}

import Control.Monad

data Count a = Count Int a
    deriving (Functor, Show)

instance Applicative Count where
    pure = return
    (<*>) = ap

instance Monad Count where
    return = Count 0
    (Count c0 a) >>= k = 
        case k a of
            Count c1 b -> Count (c0 + c1 + 1) b
```

Answer (score 12):

No, the monad laws are not enforced by the language.  But if you don't adhere to them, your code may not necessarily behave as you'd expect in some situations.  And it would certainly be confusing to users of your code.