# What are the identities categorical monads enforce that Haskell monads don't?

Tags: haskell, monads, category-theory

http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html

writes:

> If you hadn't guessed, this is about monads as they appear in pure functional programming languages like Haskell. They are closely related to the monads of category theory, but are not exactly the same because Haskell doesn't enforce the identities satisfied by categorical monads.

Are these the identities that the above text is talking about?

[Are monad laws enforced in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37124471/are-monad-laws-enforced-in-haskell)

```
return a >>= k  =  k a
m >>= return  =  m
m >>= (\x -> k x >>= h)  =  (m >>= k) >>= h
```

Comment: Yes, along with the functor laws.

Comment: Haskell might not "enforce" them - that is, the compiler won't reject otherwise correct definitions that violate them - but that's only because it would be impossible to check this in an automated way for every instance. It's still understood that any actual instances *should* satisfy the laws, or things will go wrong pretty quickly.

Comment: @RobinZigmond, not impossible -- we just need some dependent types and verification machinery.  Heh, *"just"*

Comment: @luqui I could be wrong but it seems to me there are actually deep theoretical reasons why this is impossible. You don't know what instances might be provided, and some instances might make one or both sides of a to-be-proved equality not terminate. By the impossibility of solving the Halting Problem, no algorithm can determine even that.

Comment: @chi what are those functor laws? Could you pass a link?

Comment: @Gergely did you try googling? You can find the functor laws in lots of places, here is one chosen more or less at random: https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor#Functor_Laws

Comment: @RobinZigmond I guess I was referring to an agda-style "proofs must be provided when instantiating" approach

Comment: @luqui - thanks for the reply, I confess I'm not familiar with Agda, or any dependently-typed language (I browsed through the docs for Idris a few months back, and confess a lot of it went over my head). I guess asking the programmer to provide a proof is fine, if the language provides a way to do that, but it's rather different from what I was talking about: taking any user-defined instance and being able to decide if it satisfies the laws or not. That's what I am claiming is impossible in general. (I'd be happy to be proved wrong though.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Constrasting with the accepted answer to the linked question, consider this instance.

```
newtype List a = List [a] deriving (Functor, Applicative)

instance Monad List where
    return _ = List []
    m >>= f = List []
```

A compiler will accept this definition, but it does not obey the monad laws. Specifically, try to confirm that

```
m >>= return == m
```

for both `[]` and `List`:

```
-- Correct
Prelude> [1,2,3] >>= return
[1,2,3]

-- Not correct, should be List [1,2,3]
Prelude> List [1,2,3] >>= return
List []
```